# How to get specific value from Promise Result Object in getBoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, virtual-dom, getboundingclientrect, ampscript

Here is part of my code returning a Promise, I am using getBoundingClientRect Async because it runs in AMP virtual DOM (amp-script):

JS:

```
    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event){
    
       let target = event.target;

       let coords = target.getBoundingClientRectAsync();
       
       console.log(coords);

    });
```

Console Log:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
bottom: 366
height: 38
left: 225
right: 352.234375
top: 328
width: 127.234375
x: 328
y: 225
__proto__: Object
```

How I can get value of `left` from the object Promise Result?
`coords.left;` returns undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getBoundingClientRectAsync` returns a promise, then you can use [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to get the value.

```
button.addEventListener("mouseenter", async function(event){
  let target = event.target;
  let coords = await target.getBoundingClientRectAsync();
  console.log(coords.left);
});
```

Or use the [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method of the returned Promise and set a callback where your `coords` object is made available when the Promise resolves.

```
button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event){
  let target = event.target;
  target.getBoundingClientRectAsync().then(coords => {
    console.log(coords.left);
  });
});
```

Learn the basics about Promises [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Second solution works! Await solution throws an error telling that it's not an async function for some reason. I will check out the link, much appreciated.

Comment: Standard amp-html documentation states that Element.getBoundingClientRect() is not supported, see here https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/main/web_compat_table.md . However, your provided second example DOES work in amp-html! Thank you for the helpful example!